# How to make GUI Button activate script (JS or C#) in Unity3d

Tags: variables, user-interface, unity-game-engine, runtime-error, unityscript

I really need your help to make my GUI.Button start a JS script (or C#) attached to a GameObject. Here is what I have in my application. A JS script "doRotate.js", that does a rotation on a GameObject.

The rotation starts if the value of "public var doRotation = false" is chanced to "true" by click in the Inspector

```
    #pragma strict

    public var doRotation = false;

    function Update()
    {
        if (doRotation)
        {
            transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 50, 0) * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }
```

I also have a JS script that renders some GUI.buttons. I want button 2, once pressed to call (run) the "doRotate.js" script, meaning **accessing the boolean "doRotation"** and chance its value to "true", as if it is done in the Inspector.

Following is what I've tried so far, but I get this error "Error BCE0020: An instance of type 'doRotate' is required to access non static member 'doRotation'. (BCE0020)". 
Here is the code on the GUI.button:

```
    var native_width :  float = 480;
    var native_height : float = 320;
    var addImage : Texture2D;

    var btnTexture1 : Texture;
    var btnTexture2 : Texture;


    function OnGUI ()
    {
    var rx : float = Screen.width / native_width;
    var ry : float = Screen.height / native_height;
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3 (rx, ry, 1));

    GUI.Box( Rect(20, 200, 429, 129) ,addImage, "");
      if (!btnTexture1) {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
            }

            GUI.Button(Rect(54, 222, 52, 35), btnTexture1);

    if (!btnTexture2) {
            Debug.LogError("Please assign a texture on the inspector");
            return;
            }

            if(GUI.Button(Rect(118, 222, 52, 35), btnTexture2));

                var runScript : GameObject[] =
                GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("markerObject");
                for(var doRotation : GameObject in runScript) {
                var script : doRotate = doRotation.GetComponent(doRotate);
                if(script)
                doRotate.doRotation(); //Error BCE0020: An instance of type 'doRotate' is required to access non static member 'doRotation'. (BCE0020)
            }
```

What have I done wrong? I've trying for days,to make it work without success. How can I access this variable on the click of the GUI.Button?

Can someone, please help me out?

Answer (score 1):

This error occurs because you are trying to access a nonstatic member of "doRotate" with a class, not with an instance of it.

In this following code:

```
var script : doRotate = doRotation.GetComponent(doRotate);
if(script)
   doRotate.doRotation(); //Error BCE0020: An instance of type 'doRotais    required to access non static member 'doRotation'. (BCE0020)
```

You are setting the instance of `doRotate` to var `script`, this var stores a reference of `doRotate` instance, with this you can access the var "doRotation" and change his value.

Something like this:

```
var script : doRotate = doRotation.GetComponent(doRotate);
if(script)
   script.doRotation = true;
```